# Java, parent class, method with an exception throw

Tags: java, exception

I have a method, how do I throw an exception. As opposed to try and catch.

Its a basic void method which reads in a file,

```
public void method(String filename){
//does some stuff to the file here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Easy as:

```
public void method(String filename) throws Exception
{
    if (error)
        throw new Exception("uh oh!");
}
```

or if you want a custom exception:

```
class MyException extends Exception
{
    public MyException(String reason)
    {
        super(reason);
    }
}

public void method(String filename) throws MyException
{
    if (error)
        throw new MyException("uh oh!");
}
```

Comment: And If the exception is an unchecked exception, you don't need the `throws`.

Comment: Also, add the constructor with parameter to `MyException`.

Answer (score 2):

As a first step, I think you need to go through [java Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html)

It depends on what kind of exception you want to throw

If you want to throw an unchecked exception

```
public void method(String filename){
    if(error condition){
        throw new RuntimeException(""); //Or any subclass of RuntimeException
    }
}
```

If you want to throw an checked exception

```
public void method(String filename) throws Exception{ //Here you can mention the exact type of Exception thrown like IOExcption, FileNotFoundException or a CustomException
    if(error condition){
        throw new Exception(""); //Or any subclass of Exception - Subclasses of RuntimeException
    }
}
```